# Mysql query returns duplicate entry

Tags: mysql

```
 SELECT *
 FROM ( SELECT a.*, a.id AS id_player, 
        (SELECT COUNT(id)
         FROM `vd7qw_footsal_goals`
         WHERE a.id = id_player
         AND id_group IN (SELECT id_group
                          from `vd7qw_footsal_groupofleague`
                          WHERE id_league = 2)
         ) AS goals, 
         team.team_name
         FROM `vd7qw_footsal_players` AS a
         LEFT JOIN vd7qw_footsal_teams AS team
              ON team.id = a.id_team
         LEFT JOIN vd7qw_footsal_teamofgroup AS tog
              ON tog.id_team = team.id
         LEFT JOIN vd7qw_footsal_groups AS g
              ON g.id = tog.id_group
         WHERE (a.state IN (1))
        ) AS h
 WHERE goals > 0
 ORDER BY goals DESC
```

This is my query when I have 2 or more groups in 1 league and player score a goal in each group, query returns the correct number of goals but duplicates player for example:

```
John Doe got 3 goals in group 1
```

and

```
John Doe got 4 goals in group 2
```

Query returns:

```
John Doe got 7 goals
```

where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT *
 FROM ( SELECT a.*, a.id AS id_player, (SELECT COUNT(id)
 FROM `vd7qw_footsal_goals`
 WHERE a.id = id_player
 AND id_group IN (SELECT id_group
 from `vd7qw_footsal_groupofleague`
 WHERE id_league = 2)) AS goals, team.team_name
 FROM `vd7qw_footsal_players` AS a
 LEFT JOIN vd7qw_footsal_teams AS team
 ON team.id = a.id_team
 LEFT JOIN vd7qw_footsal_teamofgroup AS tog
 ON tog.id_team = team.id
 LEFT JOIN vd7qw_footsal_groups AS g
 ON g.id = tog.id_group
 WHERE (a.state IN (1))) AS h
 WHERE goals > 0
GROUP BY id_group
 ORDER BY goals DESC
```

Comment: thanks your answer pointed me to right direction i only needed to add clause `GROUP BY` by `id_player`